# Do something on page load, based on a previous page action

Tags: php, jquery

I am building a site on wordpress and I have encountered a problem that I am not quite sure how to solve.

**The Situation:**

1. User makes a selection from a `<select>` tag on one page and submits their choice
2. User arrives at a page featuring the same `<select>`. When the user selects an option, it displays content corresponding with that option using a little bit of jQuery.

-

```
$('.result').hide();

$('#servicearea').change(function() {
  $('.result').hide();

  var optionValue = $ (this).attr('value');
  $('#'+optionValue).show('fast');

});
```

**The Problem:**

1. I need the selection from the first page to carry over to the second page then run this script.

**Solutions:**

1. I'll be honest, I don't know where to start with this, maybe cookies? I was hoping there was a jQuery type of solution as I am sort of comfortable with jQuery.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: either sessions or a hidden form field.

Comment: hidden form fields sound like they're close to my capacity, can you elaborate?

Comment: in your form on page 2 <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="*POSTED FROM PREVIOUS PAGE*"> then on page 3 you will have foo, along with the other form values

Answer (score 0):

javascript doesnt know what you have posted to the page.

you can put the value into the javascript from php with something like this:

```
<script>
    doSomething(<?=$_POST['selected'?>);
</script>
```

or you can put it into a hidden form field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="<?=$_POST['selected']?>">
```

and catch the value with

```
$('#hiddenField').val()
```

Comment: Alright,
sorry if this seems really novice. On the first page. How to I set the action to 'post' and also set it to navigation to a new page. (before the action was the link to the new page)

Answer (score 0):

Hidden form fields will work. But if you decide to go with PHP sessions instead, [take a look here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

*From the above link...*

```
<?php
// page1.php

session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #1';

$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
$_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
$_SESSION['time']     = time();

// Works if session cookie was accepted
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php">page 2</a>';

// Or maybe pass along the session id, if needed
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php?' . SID . '">page 2</a>';
?>
```

After viewing page1.php, the second page page2.php will contain the session data. [Read the session reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) for information on [propagating session ids](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) as it, for example, explains what the constant SID is all about.

```
<?php
// page2.php

session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #2<br />';

echo $_SESSION['favcolor']; // green
echo $_SESSION['animal'];   // cat
echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']);

// You may want to use SID here, like we did in page1.php
echo '<br /><a href="page1.php">page 1</a>';
?>
```

**UPDATE**

Judging by your snippet, I believe you would set the session variable by doing something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select type="select" name="servicearea" >
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>

<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['optionValue'] = $_POST['servicearea'];
}
echo $_SESSION['optionValue'];
?>
```

Comment: This looks like it could work, how do I set up the session variables to grab the html select options?

Comment: Should be pretty simple. I've added an update to the bottom of my answer with an example. Note that **$_POST['servicearea'];** will be referring to an input element in your form with the name attribute  **servicearea** (not an id attribute like in your snippet above)

Comment: First off, thanks so much! 

Second: Would I need to set up a seperate js function to handle navigating to page two, or do I do some kind of redirect with php?

Comment: Sorry I dont think this way is going to work for me. There is session conflicts with wordpress. Thanks anyways.